# MySQL Query return the whole tables when like %% is used

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When i search a table with the following query i get the result as expected

Query:

```
SELECT id,suppid,name FROM product WHERE suppid = 137 AND name LIKE '%a%' OR id LIKE '%a%'
```

Result i get:

```
+------+--------+-------------+
| id   | suppid | name        |
+------+--------+-------------+
| 1024 |    137 | Cable Modem |
| 1026 |    137 | Moto Razr   |
+------+--------+-------------+
```

But when i remove all letter from the `LIKE` part, it return the entire table, completely ignoring the `WHERE suppid = 137`.

The below query is the problem

```
SELECT id,suppid,name FROM product WHERE suppid = 137 AND name LIKE '%%' OR id LIKE '%%'
```

Result I get:

```
+------+--------+----------------+
| id   | suppid | name           |
+------+--------+----------------+
| 1001 |    130 | Router         |
| 1002 |    121 | Youtube        |
| 1003 |    114 | Bucket         |
| 1004 |    115 | Windows        |
| 1005 |    118 | Jio            |
| 1006 |    117 | Fan            |
| 1007 |    133 | Oled Display   |
| 1009 |    117 | Modem          |
| 1010 |    118 | Fibre          |
| 1011 |    113 | Stand          |
| 1012 |    135 | Broom          |
| 1013 |    135 | Welcome mat    |
| 1014 |    128 | iPhone         |
| 1015 |    128 | iPad           |
| 1016 |    136 | Redmi 3S Prime |
| 1017 |    134 | Acer           |
| 1018 |    120 | Pacel          |
| 1019 |    124 | Money Bank     |
| 1020 |    115 | Xbox           |
| 1021 |    132 | BOX 111        |
| 1022 |    136 | Redmi 4A       |
| 1023 |    130 | Wifi Adapter   |
| 1024 |    137 | Cable Modem    |
| 1025 |    136 | Note 5         |
| 1026 |    137 | Moto Razr      |
| 1027 |    137 | Moto G         |
| 1028 |    128 | iPod           |
+------+--------+----------------+
```

What causing this?

Comment: this is correct  like '%%' mean all chars ..  you have or id like'%%';

Comment: I am doing a search, eventually  characters might appear between the %%.

Comment: You can just put one % - it means zero or more characters.

Comment: based on the sample you provide what is your expected  result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
`SELECT id,suppid,name FROM product WHERE suppid = 137 AND (name LIKE '%%' OR id LIKE '%%'`)

`OR` operator takes precedence over `AND`. You need to implicitly define precedence of logic operators in such cases.

So you query 
`SELECT id,suppid,name FROM product WHERE suppid = 137 AND name LIKE '%%' OR id LIKE '%%'` reads `(WHERE suppid = 137 AND name LIKE '%%') OR id LIKE '%%'` 
So the part `OR id LIKE '%%'`  returns all ids.

Answer (score 0):

*SELECT id,suppid,name FROM product WHERE suppid = 137 AND name LIKE '%%' OR id LIKE '%%'*

**This above code is returning all the rows since Operator precedence is not working correctly resuting fetching all the rows from the table .

**Solution :-**

In order to fetch the correct Data set of records Use below Query**

SELECT id,suppid,name FROM product WHERE suppid = 137 AND (name LIKE '%%' OR id LIKE '%%') .

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a problem with the `OR` operator without parenthesis:

```
SELECT id,suppid,name FROM product WHERE suppid = 137 AND (name LIKE '%%' OR id LIKE '%%')
```

is exactly the same than

```
SELECT id,suppid,name FROM product WHERE suppid = 137
```

It's different if you use a value between the wildcard characters: `%`